# How can i make a picture appear in a java applet?

Tags: java, applet, loading, image

I have looked all over the internet for a clear answer but it is just some people typing the coding and not explaining how and where to enter it. I'm new to java and i want to try to make a 2D game but i don't know how to make a picture appear in the applet. I need a clear answer of what the code should look like and where and when to enter it cause i'm not too good at it but i'm good enough to follow instructions. *Optional* And if anyone can help me with menus in the same answer you would be my best friend.

Comment: there are lots of demos with examples here: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html)

Comment: lol ben, i have looked at the same site for menus, only problem is that they don't want to load

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to start coding by copying and pasting snippets. At this level I think you're better off getting a good book on Java programming.

You'll want something which has a chapters on Applets + AWT and / or Swing. By the end of that I think you'll see how to achieve your aim.

Programming by copy / paste without first principals is a really good way to get confused and end up with something which probably won't work.

Comment: Damn AP class has me in that habit cause the teacher provides most of the code and we edit it to make the program work, although i'm looking into things that is more advanced than what we are learning, that the problem

Comment: Is see - I guess in a structured environment that can be a valid way of learning. If you've got an applet working before in class you should find the next step fairly easy. Do some reading on Swing to orient yourself, you should find you figure out how to do this fairly quickly and you'll pick up necessary learning on the way.

Comment: This would be a good start, and if you're planning to write a game the section on concurrency will be very helpful so I wouldn't skip it...

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html